# FlashPlayer Stop

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have created a flash player object for playing videos from youtube

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxx";
```

which work its, but I can't get it to stop playing when I use this code

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Stop();
```

or

```
axShockwaveFlash1.StopPlay();
```

help me please.. Is possible to stop the video?

Comment: What is `axShockwaveFlash1`? Is this something you built from scratch? Third party component?